# View values of a file uploaded on django-rest-framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upload multiple files to from an angular frontend,
I want to  be able to view or access the values of each file before performing any extra manipulations on them.
How do I view the contents of each file?

```
@list_route(methods=['PUT'])
def uploads(self, request):
    print(request.data['files'])
    for file_item in request.data.getlist('files'):
        print(file_item)
    return Response(0)
```

this is the result I get when i print the contents.

```
[object File],[object File]
```

this is the array of files that was sent from the client.

```
File(8614)
lastModified : 1522947934000
name: "passport.jpeg"
size: 8614
type: "image/jpeg"

File(8610)
lastModified : 1522947934800
name: "passport2.jpeg"
size: 8610
type: "image/jpeg"
```